# get first comment of a Facebook user

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to integrate Facebook API to my web app. I want to check approximately when the user joined Facebook by querying earliest comment like following:

`SELECT text, time FROM comment WHERE fromid= me() ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 1`

However, I got error saying:

`"message": "Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column.`

How can I fix this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The comment table is for fb:comments, so you need to use the proper table first. This would be the *status* table. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/status.

```
 SELECT status_id, message, time FROM status WHERE uid=me() ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 1
```

### But

> What if the first post is from another user?

Then we should use the stream table. The first item in the news feed, should theoretically be after the date of joining (why show items before?) This is assuming the API holds all the data for the news feed.

So this will involve playing with *streams*, filter_keys and created_time

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream_filter
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream

Comment: phwd: thanks for the suggestion. I tried status table, but realized that my friends (including myself) who joined Facebook early on didn't have status at the beginning (2004 to 2007). I am not sure if this feature was available back then. Therefore, this would not be a good approximate of time joining Facebook.

Comment: @AdamNYC sorry that's the limitation of the API, I'm just clarifying that you are querying the wrong tables anyway...

Comment: @AdamNYC `The comment table is for fb:comments` meaning the Facebook Comments plugin for websites which is not equivalent to status messages or posts on a user's wall/timeline.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the tip. I guess I should extract from like table then.

Answer (score 0):

A FQL query with a `WHERE` clause must include an indexable column, as shown in [the docs for the table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/) (they're now marked with a star, & shown in the *Supported Base Where Clauses* section).

`fromid` is not an indexable column so your `WHERE` clause can't be just a condition on this column.

I don't think it's possible to discover when a user joined Facebook via the Graph API or FQL; there's no property of [the FQL `User` table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user) that gives this, & the Graph API User schema is pretty close to the `User` table.

Comment: Hi Richard, I don't use `time` in `WHERE` statement. I used `fromid`, and this variable is not indexed., so I need a way to get around this.

Comment: Doh, misread your query; edited my answer to fix.  IMO there is no way to discover when a user joined Facebook.  Date of first comment is not accurate anyway.  In many cases the api only provides recent data anyway.